# Decompress byte array in node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, compression, pako

We currently have a project in android and company wants to do some parts on server. Server side code in with Node JS. The thing I want to do looks very simple but I am stuck on that. 
We have a long byte array which is compressed, in the android project I have his code that works fine and decompress the byte array. I want to do same in Node JS but I got the error `incorrect data check`.

```
public byte[] decompressBytes(byte[] compressedBytes) {
    try {
        Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
        decompresser.setInput(compressedBytes);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[2048];

        while(!decompresser.finished()) {
            int cnt = decompresser.inflate(buf);
            if(cnt <= 0) {
                break;
            }

            bos.write(buf, 0, cnt);
        }

        bos.close();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception var6) {
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

Here is the code I wrote form the documents of `Pako` but as I told it returns error.

```
function decompress(data, callback) {

    var response = '';

    var pako = require('pako');
    try {
        response = pako.inflate(actData);
        console.log("response : " + response);
        callback('', response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err, '');
    }
}
```

The inputs are exactly same byte array.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting from Pako?

It looks like you're trying to inflate `actData`, but you're passing in `data` as the parameter. Is that a typo?